# Get date from timestamp in NSIS

Tags: date, timestamp, nsis

I'm very new to [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page), and I'm trying to get a date, hour, minutes, etc. from the given timestamp.

Is it any way to do that?

Thank you in advance for any answers...

Comment: What kind of timestamp? 32-bit unix time (in seconds)? Windows FILETIME?

Comment: It is standard Unix timestamp, like 1568807339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
StrCpy $0 1568807339 ; UNIX time
System::Int64Op $0 * 10000000
System::Int64Op 116444736000000000 + ; support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167296/how-to-convert-a-unix-time-t-to-a-win32-filetime-or-systemtime
System::Call 'KERNEL32::FileTimeToLocalFileTime(*ls,*l.s)' ; This line is optional, comment it out if you want to keep it UTC
System::Call 'KERNEL32::FileTimeToSystemTime(*ls,@r0)i.r1' ; NSIS v3+
${If} $1 <> 0
    System::Call '*$0(&i2.r1,&i2.r2,&i2,&i2.r3,&i2.r4,&i2.r5,&i2.r6)'
    IntFmt $2 "%.2d" $2
    IntFmt $3 "%.2d" $3
    IntFmt $4 "%.2d" $4
    IntFmt $5 "%.2d" $5
    IntFmt $6 "%.2d" $6
    DetailPrint "$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6"

    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetDateFormat(i0x0400,i0,pr0,p0,t.r1,i666)'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetTimeFormat(i0x0400,i0,pr0,p0,t.r2,i666)'
    DetailPrint "$1 $2"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!